# Is there a way to thread methods in java, instead of the entire class?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I've been wondering,
recently, in school, we've been learning about java threads..

Unlike most other languages, I haven't found a way to thread a function in java yet, which is really what I'm looking for...

I know one could use the run class, but imagine a class has 3 functions, each with their own
parameters, i'd like to be able to call those functions and thread them seperatly if possible...

Comment: Your class needs to implement Thread so you can invoke run method and execute two tasks or more at the same time. There is no standalone way to implement multithreading.

Comment: What do you mean by 'thread a class' or 'thread a function'? In Java, you create threads and define what they do. you don't do either of those things.

Comment: Also `run` is not a class. It is the method that is executed whenever a newly created thread is started.

Comment: @kellax Did you mean "implement Runnable"?

Comment: @kellax There is almost never a reason to extend `Thread`, instead you should implement `Runnable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
         functionToThread();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: +1, however the OP should know that you're still threading an object and not just a function, even though that object isn't user-defined.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct. This was the closest example I could think of that gave the feeling of "calling a function into another thread"

Answer (score 4):

The correct approach to achieve multi-threading in Java is to implement `Runnable`. Extending the `Thread` class is just a convenient slightly simpler way, but implementing the `Runnable` interface is best, because it gives you the method `run()` in which you can call your function and also allows you to extend other classes instead of `Thread`.

What you don't have access to however is the return value of the function you are executing in the other Thread. For this you can use the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which gives you an object which will get populated with your return value, as soon as the other thread executes the function. Instead of implementing `Runnable` you implement [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), which is very similar, with its method called `call()` instead of `run()`, and allowing you to specify the return type through Generics. `Future` objects can also be used with thread pools and task executors. Look at the example in the javadoc of the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) class, it has a good example and explanation.

Also remember that within a method you can create an anonymous class, so if you're simply after that you just do it inline (extending `Runnable` or `Callable`) within the method you want to execute in a separate thread. (As Cruncher indicated in his answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create separate wrapper classes that either implement `Runnable` or extend thread and call your functions.

BTW even if java had kind of method pointers like C has you still need some wrapper that knows the values of parameters you want to pass to the functions.

Comment: This is actually coming in Java 8 with lambda expressions :) http://www.geekyarticles.com/2012/01/whats-cooking-in-java-8-project-lambda.html